# How to extract type definitions from OCaml code

Tags: ocaml

Is there any way to extract all the type definitions from a bunch of OCaml files? I can always cut and paste them into a separate editor tab, where it's easy to stare at them in a way that fits as much information on the screen at possible. However, this is a chore and I'd prefer to make it automated.

To make it precise, Emacs and tuareg mode already shows me the types of all the functions, but what I'd also want is to be able to collect a nice cheat sheet of what each type actually is. For modules, there's obviously the mli-file, but for everything else collecting them into one place to quickly get an overview of a bunch of code is annoying.

Comment: doesn't fhe language have a parser for itself? btw I would avoid asking about tools in a SO thread — that's like begging for a *Closed as Off Topic*.

Comment: Yes, of course I could grab the source code of the parser and write it myself. However, I have other things on my plate and was hoping there is a way to do this and that has already been implemented by someone.

Comment: @Erik: Well, I'm not asking "what's the best tool/ide/...", which tend to get closed. However, I'm usually a bad judge regarding what people think of as off-topic, so I don't care.

Comment: *How to extract...* would give you equally good answers.

Comment: Alright, I'll remove the word tool, although it won't change the question one bit. :)

Comment: Generate mli with ocamlc -i or use ocamldoc

Comment: @camlspotter: I'm not looking at generating a module interface from an implementation. What I'm looking for is something that collects all "type foo = ..." stuff and all "module X = MakeFoo(struct ... end) (Y)" from the source into one place. AFAIK, ocamldoc can't do this either.

Comment: Iow you want code folding?

Comment: Code folding hides functions from view, which helps with this, yes, but is not what I'm looking for. I already use it with both Emacs and Sublime.

Comment: I don't understand how generating the mli (or writing them yourself), doesn't create the situation you're looking for (of having all the type information in one place). Could you better describe why that isn't a solution? You say 'modules, there's obviously the mli files', but modules are EVERYTHING!

Comment: I think you need to give an example of what you expect for us to understand what you mean.

Comment: Or perhaps your code has too many types involved in one place? Perhaps you need to break it down into many more manageable files?

Comment: Or maybe you are thinking about something like ocamloscope : http://ocamloscope.herokuapp.com ?

Comment: I'll update the question, since it looks like ocamlc -i can do this, since it's pretty trivial to filter out function types from the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very difficult to understand what you're asking for. Maybe it will help if I collect everybody's suggestions into one place.

As nlucaroni points out, you can't say you have a solution for modules but you want something that works for everything else. There is nothing else. All OCaml code is part of a module.

You say that mli files are OK. If a module doesn't have an mli file, you can generate an mli file for it with `ocamlc -i` as camlspotter says.

If this doesn't work, give an example of some OCaml code and what extracted definitions you want to see for it.

Comment: Turns out I was a bit hasty with my comment above. What I wanted to do can be done with ocamlc -i and passing the output through a simple shell script.